# Can't install any drivers at all on Windows 8. Error 0x000003F9

Tags: windows-8, installation, drivers

I suddenly can't install any drivers at all on my Windows 8 Pro x64 install. It doesn't matter what kind of driver it is, nothing will install. Everything ends with error 0x000003F9: The system has attempted to load or restore a file into the registry, but the specified file is not in a registry file format. When Windows Update tries to install a driver, it just gives error code 800703F9 and says that "Windows Update ran into a problem."
I've already done a scan of system files with sfc, tried another user account, done a chkdsk, and a few more things, but nothing works.

The problem started when I tried to install drivers for my printer earlier today and suddenly started getting messages saying that "Windows Modules Installer has stopped working." I decided to restart and was being greeted with the recovery boot options. I shut the computer down, but when I booted it back up the same thing happened, so I did a repair your pc, and was able to boot into the OS properly. Then I rebooted into my external drive and did a chkdsk on the Windows 8 install that started acting funny. When I booted back into Windows 8, I wasn't able to install any drivers. They all keep coming up with the same error. And I can't seem to find anything at all on this issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's an install log from a failed driver install:

```
>>>  [Device Install (DiInstallDriver) - F:\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf]
>>>  Section start 2012/12/06 20:15:20.714
  cmd: "F:\Windows\System32\InfDefaultInstall.exe" "F:\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf"
 inf: {SetupCopyOEMInf: F:\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf} 20:15:20.716
 sto:      {Import Driver Package: F:\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf} 20:15:20.719
 sto:           Driver Store   = F:\Windows\System32\DriverStore [Online] (6.2.9200)
 sto:           Driver Package = F:\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf
 sto:           Architecture   = amd64
 sto:           Flags          = 0x00000000
 inf:           Provider       = Google, Inc.
 inf:           Class GUID     = {3f966bd9-fa04-4ec5-991c-d326973b5128}
 inf:           Driver Version = 08/27/2012,7.0.0.1
 inf:           Catalog File   = androidwinusba64.cat
 inf:           Version Flags  = 0x00000011
!    sto:           Unable to determine presence of driver package 'android_winusb.inf'. Error = 0x000003F9
 flq:           Copying 'F:\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\amd64\WdfCoInstaller01009.dll' to 'F:\Users\ALEXBA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{5da5e23e-2f82-2b4f-b73d-9d77c2978b0e}\amd64\WdfCoInstaller01009.dll'.
 flq:           Copying 'F:\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\amd64\WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll' to 'F:\Users\ALEXBA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{5da5e23e-2f82-2b4f-b73d-9d77c2978b0e}\amd64\WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll'.
 flq:           Copying 'F:\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf' to 'F:\Users\ALEXBA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{5da5e23e-2f82-2b4f-b73d-9d77c2978b0e}\android_winusb.inf'.
 flq:           Copying 'F:\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\androidwinusba64.cat' to 'F:\Users\ALEXBA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{5da5e23e-2f82-2b4f-b73d-9d77c2978b0e}\androidwinusba64.cat'.
 pol:           {Driver package policy check} 20:15:20.814
 pol:           {Driver package policy check - exit(0x00000000)} 20:15:20.814
 sto:           {Stage Driver Package: F:\Users\ALEXBA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{5da5e23e-2f82-2b4f-b73d-9d77c2978b0e}\android_winusb.inf} 20:15:20.815
!    sto:                Unable to determine presence of driver package 'android_winusb.inf'. Error = 0x000003F9
 inf:                {Query Configurability: F:\Users\ALEXBA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{5da5e23e-2f82-2b4f-b73d-9d77c2978b0e}\android_winusb.inf} 20:15:20.820
 inf:                     Driver package uses WDF.
 inf:                     Driver package 'android_winusb.inf' is configurable.
 inf:                {Query Configurability: exit(0x00000000)} 20:15:20.823
 flq:                Copying 'F:\Users\ALEXBA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{5da5e23e-2f82-2b4f-b73d-9d77c2978b0e}\amd64\WdfCoInstaller01009.dll' to 'F:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{30801e6d-d30f-2f4b-87dc-c80122d5f248}\amd64\WdfCoInstaller01009.dll'.
 flq:                Copying 'F:\Users\ALEXBA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{5da5e23e-2f82-2b4f-b73d-9d77c2978b0e}\amd64\WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll' to 'F:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{30801e6d-d30f-2f4b-87dc-c80122d5f248}\amd64\WinUSBCoInstaller2.dll'.
 flq:                Copying 'F:\Users\ALEXBA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{5da5e23e-2f82-2b4f-b73d-9d77c2978b0e}\android_winusb.inf' to 'F:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{30801e6d-d30f-2f4b-87dc-c80122d5f248}\android_winusb.inf'.
 flq:                Copying 'F:\Users\ALEXBA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{5da5e23e-2f82-2b4f-b73d-9d77c2978b0e}\androidwinusba64.cat' to 'F:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{30801e6d-d30f-2f4b-87dc-c80122d5f248}\androidwinusba64.cat'.
 sto:                {DRIVERSTORE IMPORT VALIDATE} 20:15:20.875
 sig:                     {_VERIFY_FILE_SIGNATURE} 20:15:20.881
 sig:                          Key      = android_winusb.inf
 sig:                          FilePath = F:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{30801e6d-d30f-2f4b-87dc-c80122d5f248}\android_winusb.inf
 sig:                          Catalog  = F:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{30801e6d-d30f-2f4b-87dc-c80122d5f248}\androidwinusba64.cat
!    sig:                          Verifying file against specific (valid) catalog failed! (0x800b0109)
!    sig:                          Error 0x800b0109: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.
 sig:                     {_VERIFY_FILE_SIGNATURE exit(0x800b0109)} 20:15:20.893
 sig:                     {_VERIFY_FILE_SIGNATURE} 20:15:20.893
 sig:                          Key      = android_winusb.inf
 sig:                          FilePath = F:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{30801e6d-d30f-2f4b-87dc-c80122d5f248}\android_winusb.inf
 sig:                          Catalog  = F:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{30801e6d-d30f-2f4b-87dc-c80122d5f248}\androidwinusba64.cat
 sig:                          Success: File is signed in Authenticode(tm) catalog.
 sig:                          Error 0xe0000242: The publisher of an Authenticode(tm) signed catalog has not yet been established as trusted.
 sig:                     {_VERIFY_FILE_SIGNATURE exit(0xe0000242)} 20:15:20.907
!    sig:                     Driver package signer is unknown, but user trusts signer.
 sto:                {DRIVERSTORE IMPORT VALIDATE: exit(0x00000000)} 20:15:22.701
 sig:                Signer Score = 0x0F000000
 sig:                Signer Name  = Google Inc
 sto:                {DRIVERSTORE IMPORT BEGIN} 20:15:22.702
 sto:                {DRIVERSTORE IMPORT BEGIN: exit(0x00000000)} 20:15:22.702
 cpy:                {Copy Directory: F:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{30801e6d-d30f-2f4b-87dc-c80122d5f248}} 20:15:22.703
 cpy:                     Target Path = F:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\android_winusb.inf_amd64_f7c4b212c9d862a3
 cpy:                     {Copy Directory: F:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{30801e6d-d30f-2f4b-87dc-c80122d5f248}\amd64} 20:15:22.704
 cpy:                          Target Path = F:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\android_winusb.inf_amd64_f7c4b212c9d862a3\amd64
 cpy:                     {Copy Directory: exit(0x00000000)} 20:15:22.705
 cpy:                {Copy Directory: exit(0x00000000)} 20:15:22.706
!    sto:                Unable to determine if driver package 'android_winusb.inf' is already registered. Error = 0x000003F9
 idb:                {Register Driver Package: F:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\android_winusb.inf_amd64_f7c4b212c9d862a3\android_winusb.inf} 20:15:22.707
!!!  idb:                     Failed to create driver package object 'android_winusb.inf_amd64_f7c4b212c9d862a3' in DRIVERS database node. Error = 0x000003F9
!!!  idb:                     Failed to register driver package 'F:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\android_winusb.inf_amd64_f7c4b212c9d862a3\android_winusb.inf'. Error = 0x000003F9
 idb:                {Register Driver Package: exit(0x000003f9)} 20:15:22.709
 sto:                {DRIVERSTORE IMPORT END} 20:15:22.710
 sto:                {DRIVERSTORE IMPORT END: exit(0x000003f9)} 20:15:22.710
 sto:                Rolled back driver package import.
!!!  sto:                Failed to import driver package into Driver Store. Error = 0x000003F9
 sto:           {Stage Driver Package: exit(0x000003f9)} 20:15:22.736
 sto:      {Import Driver Package: exit(0x000003f9)} 20:15:22.766
```

Comment: I would attempt to use a restoration point.  At this point your installation is corrupt.

Comment: I would have tried doing a system restore, but there weren't any available. Does Windows 8 have the ability to do a repair install like previous versions did? I mean, there's the system refresh, but does that keep all your programs and stuff installed?

Comment: It also has the ability to `Reset` or `Refresh` your system.  `Refresh` will mean you keep your user files but will have to install your applications and make any system configurations changes again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means this:

```
//
// MessageId: ERROR_NOT_REGISTRY_FILE
//
// MessageText:
//
// The system has attempted to load or restore a file into the registry, but the specified file is not in a registry file format.
//
#define ERROR_NOT_REGISTRY_FILE          1017L
```

So, it looks like you have registry issues. use the metioned refresh/Reset options to fix the issues.